# Restoring a backup of 1 database to another puts both databases into Restoring mode

Tags: sql-server-2012, backup, restore

We have a 2 databases-

- Staging
- Test

At times, we refresh out `Test` environment with a copy of `Staging`. We do this by taking a full backup of the `Staging` database and restoring it over the `Test` database.

When we do this, both databases go into `Restoring...` mode and only the `Test` databases comes back online after the restore.. the `Staging` database shows `Restoring...` until we issue a `RESTORE DATABASE Staging WITH RECOVERY`.

Why is this and what do we need to change about our process to prevent this happening?
The backup and restore event log on the `Staging` database doesn't show any evidence of a restore on the database.

I'm thinking it's something to do with Logical File Names. When we do the restore, we change the `.dbf` and `.ldf` files to point to the TEST files, however the logical files are still pointing to `STAGING`, something we can't change through SSMS during a restore.

The restore command that SSMS is running is:

```
USE [master]
BACKUP LOG [Chris21_STAGING] TO  DISK = N'F:\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\Chris21_STAGING_LogBackup_2016-06-24_11-12-03.bak' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'Chris21_STAGING_LogBackup_2016-06-24_11-12-03', NOSKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  NORECOVERY ,  STATS = 5
ALTER DATABASE [Chris21_TEST] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
RESTORE DATABASE [Chris21_TEST] FROM  DISK = N'C:\Chris21_STAGING Backup 20160624.bak' WITH  FILE = 1,  MOVE N'Chris21_STAGING' TO N'F:\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\Chris21_TEST.mdf',  MOVE N'Chris21_STAGING_log' TO N'F:\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\Chris21_TEST_log.ldf',  NOUNLOAD,  REPLACE,  STATS = 5
ALTER DATABASE [Chris21_TEST] SET MULTI_USER
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that in UI you have 'Backup tail of the log, and leave database in restoring state' selected which is causing the issue. - https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/46744